# Adding onclick events to appended div tags in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am trying to add a click event to a bunch of div elements that I created by appending them and I am having some trouble.

I have a bunch of div elements the with the ids a0 ---> an. I am trying to create a for loop after the divs are created to assign them click events. The issue is the way I am doing it when the click event happens I do not have any way to track which div fired the event. The code bellow might make that more clear. So the issue I am having is that #a + i always returns the last div, and I want it to return the div number that was clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            traverse(oo);
            for (i = 0; i <= groupNum; i += 1) {
                $("#a" + i).click(function () {
                    console.log("#a" + i + "clicked");
                });
            }
        });
```

I thought about returning a closeur, but that seems I would make it even more complicated. Does anybody have any advice on how to do this the best?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: istead of `id` you can use `class` if ids are to be assigned with `0...N` and use `.index()` to get the corresponding element.

Comment: It is a [javascript closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) issue.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean it is a Javascript closures issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but if you just want to assign a click event to a bunch of elements then use the correct selector (note the use of `$(this)` to get the clicked element):

```
$("div").click(function(){
   var clickedDiv = $(this);
   var id = clickedDiv.attr("id");
});
```

---

If you don't want ALL `div` elements, then you could add a class to them and use a different selector:

```
$(".MyDivClass").click(function(){...
```

or without the class, a 'starts with' on the `id` (the following with get all `div` elements where the `id` attribute starts with "a"):

```
$("div[id^='a']").click(function(){...
```

---

If you are dynamically adding divs with other javascript and you want them to automatically have the click events, use the `on` function...

```
$(document).on("click", ".MyDivClass", function(){...
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `i` will, as you noticed, will contains the value set on the last iteration. Change

```
console.log("#a" + i + "clicked");
```

by

```
console.log(this.id + " clicked");
```

Within the event handler, `this` is the target DOM element for the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
$('[id^="a"]').click(function () {
  console.log(this.id+" clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may assign a click event to a class instead of to specific ID's and use conditional statements within the click function to do different things base on ID.

```
    $(documnet).ready(function(){
        $('.clickclass').click(function(){
                  /* conditional code here */
        });
    });
```